# Overlap texts or pictures at specific positions above an array

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, graphics, overlays

I have a frame which contains a piece of code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{title}
   \begin{array}{l}
      int v \\
      v = 1 \\
      v = v + 1 \\
      ...
   \end{array}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I would like to realise the following thing (with `overlay` probably):

1. In the first place, the presentation only shows the code
2. In the next slide, a block of text (or picture) will be added and pointed to `int v` to say for instance `a declaration`
3. In the next slide, a block of text (or picture) will be added and pointed to `v = 1` to say for instance `an assignment`
4. In the next slide, a block of text (or picture) will be added and pointed to `v = v + 1` to say for instance `an incrementation`

I hope the position of the blocks of text (or picture) could be specified and adjusted.

This kind of things is easy to realise in e.g., Microsoft Powerpoint, but I don't know if it is easy to do in LaTex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a possible solution. I couldn't manage to make the "mouse-click-progress" work, but it will work if you click the right arrow.

I'll try to have a look later and see if I can include that.

### Code

```
\documentclass[step]{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
%\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark, arrows.meta}

\newcommand{\mymark}[1]{%
    \tikz[remember picture,overlay]{\node[anchor=south, minimum size=2mm, inner sep=0, outer sep=0] (#1) {};}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{onlyenv}<1->%
\begin{textblock}{5}(1,5)
int v\mymark{a} \\%
v = 1\mymark{b} \\%
v = v + 1\mymark{c} \\%
... \\%
\end{textblock}
\end{onlyenv}
\begin{onlyenv}<2->
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[<-, {Latex}-] (a) --++ (3,2) node[anchor=west] {a declaration};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{onlyenv}
\begin{onlyenv}<3->
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[<-, {Latex}-] (a) --++ (3,2) node[anchor=west] {a declaration};
\draw[<-, {Latex}-] (b) --++ (3,0) node[anchor=west] {an assignment};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{onlyenv}
\begin{onlyenv}<4->
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[<-, {Latex}-] (a) --++ (3,2) node[anchor=west] {a declaration};
\draw[<-, {Latex}-] (b) --++ (3,0) node[anchor=west] {an assignment};
\draw[<-, {Latex}-] (c) --++ (4,-2) node[anchor=west] {an incrementation};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{onlyenv}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I was not very clear... "mouse-click-progress" does not matter, I just meant "next slide"...

Comment: @SoftTimur I don't understand what you mean.